# SQL Selecting all records with composite key

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, dynamic

Here is the table structure, with the first 6 columns as composite keys.

```
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5    col6    col7    col8
A1  A2  A3  A4  A5  1   xx  yy
A1  A2  A3  A4  A5  2   xxx yyy
A1  A2  A3  A4  A5  3   a   b
A1  B2  A3  A4  A5  4   aa  bb
B1  A2  A3  A4  A5  5   aaa bbb
B1  B2  B3  B4  B5  6   d   e
B1  B2  B3  B4  B5  7   dd  ee
B1  B3  C3  B4  B5  8   ddd eee
```

I need a stored procedure which returns the values like below

```
A1  A2  A3  A4  A5  xx  yy  xxx yyy a   b
A1  B2  A3  A4  A5  aa  bb
B1  A2  A3  A4  A5  aaa bbb     
B1  B2  B3  B4  B5  d   e   dd  ee
B1  B2  C3  B4  B5  ddd eee
```

Any pointers or help is appreciated.

Comment: In your results, the first 5 values are simple enough.  But then you have different numbers of columns for each row.  SQL just doesn't support that.  Do you want "xx, yy, xxx, yyy, a, b" (for example) to be returned as a single string?  And if so, why?  Denormalising like this feels like something may be wrong in the approach, and if we know what you want to achieve we may be able to offer a different approach.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.If the first five columns are same for the rows, i hav to display the values in a single row in a table.yes the columns will change dynamically according to duplicate rows for first 5 columns.I am new to sql queries.i am not sure whether its possible or not.

Comment: The short answer is "No, you can't have dynamic numbers of columns".  If you describe what you need this result *for* then we may be able to offer an alternative.

Comment: Each result set from SQL has a particular shape - it has a certain number of columns, each of those (named) columns has a particular data type. It sounds like you want a report generator, not SQL.

Comment: i need to show the result on a grid in winform as above.

Comment: @Dems is it possible to return that as single string in stored procedure ex:A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 "xx,yy,xxx,yyy,a,b". An example might help.

Comment: If you *really* want to do that, an answer just appeared below.  But I recommend an alternative approach.  De-couple your data from your presentation.  Your SQL query should select the record pretty much as you demonstrated them in you example input.  Then the winform code *processes* that data into a different shape.  With sub-reports, differing columns, or whatever.  Tying SQL directly to Presentation is a recipe for future pain.  (In my experience)

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a result like this:

```
A1  A2  A3  A4  A5  xx,yy,xxx,yyy,a,b
A1  B2  A3  A4  A5  aa,bb
B1  A2  A3  A4  A5  aaa,bbb
B1  B2  B3  B4  B5  d,e,dd,ee
B1  B3  C3  B4  B5  ddd,eee
```

Then a simple query will do:

```
  select COL1
        ,COL2
        ,COL3
        ,COL4
        ,COL5
        ,LISTAGG(COL7 || ',' || COL8, ',') within group (order by COL6)
    from TAB1
group by COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4, COL5
order by COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4, COL5
```

To get a dynamic number of columns you need to create a dynamic SQL. See [this](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:7086279412131) article for a guide on that.

Comment: I am working on sql server 2005.I am not getting  what is LISTAGG

Comment: My answer was for Oracle. I'll update the tags in your question to indicate SQL-Server. Look at [this](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/) article on a way to concatenate rows in SQL-Server.

Answer (score 0):

First, as a standard result set from a query, you cant return variable numbers of columns, you can however return on column which is a xml column (intoduced in SQL 2005) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345117%28v=sql.90%29.aspx which you can then bind to. The binding will have to be dynamic.You can use the pivot function http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx may be of help in presenting the data in the format you want - or as stated above you can use dynamic SQL. If you do this you should generate your dynamic SQL inside a stored procedure and use sp_executesql to execute the string you generate http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175170.aspx you'll probably need to pass parameters http://support.microsoft.com/kb/262499 to guard against injection attacks. Quite a few steps to learn... however each step is not particularly difficult and its a great exercise!

Comment: well most of the links have example scripts, the way I do it is to start with a basic select, prove that works, create a script to generate that select and sp_executesql it. Then step by step modify the generating script, saving each version so I can go back when I have completely messed up. It is a very powerful technique to learn, and I'm afraid the only way to really learn is dive in and try it.

Answer (score 0):

check this, don't know it helps you or not. I used sql server 2008, it returns result as per your requirments.

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5,
(SELECT ' ' + col7 + ' ' + col8  FROM TABLE1 t1 
WHERE t1.col1 = t.col1 and t1.col2 = t.col2 and 
t1.col3 = t.col3 and t1.col4 = t.col4 and t1.col5 = t.col5
ORDER BY col6
FOR XML PATH('')) AS mearge_col
FROM TABLE1 t 
GROUP BY col1, col2, col3, col4, col5
```